# How to retrieve datas from dynamically created table in html

Tags: html, struts2

Im generating html table dynamically with some textbox and dropdownlist, user will enter their input in that. how to retrieve that data and pass to Action class using struts2

Answer (score 0):

1 You must add row identifier every row parameters in your table

```
  <form action="/my_action_path/my_action.do">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          //This is your row id
          <input type="hidden" name="rowId" value="**1**"/>

          <input type="text" name="first_textbox_**1**"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="second_textbox_**1**"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          //This is your row id
          <input type="hidden" name="rowId" value="**2**"/>

          <input type="text" name="first_textbox_**2**"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="second_textbox_**2**"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit"/>
  </form>
```

2 Here is the action code

```
import java.lang.String;

public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {
  //Struts put all your "rowId" values here
  private String[] rowId = new String[];

  public String execute(){
  //Get "request" object
    HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
  //Read all your parameters using they names
    for(int i = 0; i< rowId.length; i++){
      String firstTextbox = (String) request.getParameter("first_textbox" + "_" + i);
      String secondTextbox = (String) request.getParameter("second_textbox" + "_" + i);
      //Ta-dam. Your have your parameters from the row i
    }
  }

  public String[] getRowId() {
    return rowId;
  }

  public void setRowId(String[] rowId) {
    this.rowId = rowId;
  }
}
```